# How to sort a python list of lists by both the values of a nested list and with a condition of reverse=True for only first value of the nested list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting

I am trying to sort this list by both the values of the nested list, but I want only alphabets positions in reverse order and the numbers in ascending order.

```
sample_list = [
  ['y', 4], 
  ['x', 2], 
  ['y', 1], 
  ['z', 2], 
  ['x', 5], 
  ['y', 2]]

sorted_list = sorted(sample_list, key=lambda nested: (nested[0], nested[1]), reverse=True)
```

Output:

```
[['z', 2], 
 ['y', 4], 
 ['y', 2], 
 ['y', 1], 
 ['x', 5], 
 ['x', 2]]
```

Expected Output:

```
[['z', 2], 
 ['y', 1], 
 ['y', 2], 
 ['y', 4], 
 ['x', 2], 
 ['x', 5]]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `-nested[1]` in your lambda function.

```
>>> sorted_list = sorted(sample_list, key=lambda nested: (nested[0],-nested[1]), reverse=True)
>>> print(*sorted_list,sep='\n')                                                                   
['z', 2]
['y', 1]
['y', 2]
['y', 4]
['x', 2]
['x', 5]
```

Comment: Good one. You can avoid casting to `int` as it is already one.

Answer (score 2):

The answer from "abc" is a good one for your example data, but in general if you want to sort by multiple keys in different orders, you may not be able to negate some of them (e.g. if the values are all strings rather than numbers).  In such a case you can sort multiple times to control the order of each sort key:

```
sorted_1 = sorted(sample_list, key=lambda nested: nested[1])
sorted_0_1 = sorted(sorted_1, key=lambda nested: nested[0], reverse=True)
```

This sort of thing is explained in the official documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html

This might take more time than a single `sorted()` invocation, but it will work on any sortable data, not only that which can be negated.

Comment: Last time I checked, this took *less* time.